# PriMus not working after updating Python

Tags: software-update, high-sierra, python

I installed a Python update, and now I'm having problems with opening a program called '[PriMus](http://www.columbussoft.de/index.php?lang=en)':

> CrossOver is unable to initialize a critical component. Failed to import cxutils module into Python. See console for errors. The program will now exit.

How can I fix this?

Comment: CrossOver is a *Windows compatibility layer for macOS* and allows some/a lot of Windows apps (which wouldn't launch otherwise) to run in macOS. To get your python  install location open Terminal.app and enter `which python` followed by the Enter key. To get the version simply enter `python` and hit the Enter key again. Quit python by entering `quit()` at the >>> prompt. Add the two results to your question by [editing](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/306423/edit) it. To quit Terminal.app enter `exit` and cmd-Q.

Comment: How did you install the Python update? Did you try reinstalling PriMus again?

Comment: Yes i did, it doesn't help